# Loading manually created iptables script on boot-up

Tags: firewall, iptables, boot

At present I use the script generated by `iptables-save` to be loaded at boot up. This are the [partial] contents of `/etc/iptables.rules`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Sat Mar 19 15:35:11 2011
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [218073:19652132]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [75792:5067692]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [68177:4555584]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Mar 19 15:35:11 2011
```

And I have this line in the `etc/network/interfaces` under the interface that should be firewalled:

`pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules`

This system has become tedious for me as I have to change the rules frequently, and whenever I change the rules I need to generate another `iptables.rules` file and do a system boot up to see if the the rules get applied or not. Can it be done as like conf files which load at whenever `service firewall restart` is done. And within the main iptables conf file another iptables rules file can be linked which can be made editable by users who have less privileges.  I want iptables rules to be written directly in a text file which gets loaded at boot-up or when `service firewall restart` is done.

Comment: What distro do you run? Debian or RedHat based?

Comment: It is ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are on a DEBIAN based system, because RH/Centos distros are coming with init script included.

For Ubuntu install iptables-persistent

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

and should be enough.

For Debian you can get the script from where: http://www.ubuntucy.org/wiki/index.php/A_persistent_iptables_startup_script_for_Debian_based_systems

To add it at boot use update-rc.d. I presume you saved the script on /etc/init.d/iptables, run:

```
update-rc.d iptables defaults
```

and you are done.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I do have the question of *why* you have to change your iptables ruleset all the time.

However, if you just want to test-out some new rules, here's how:

1. Do `iptables-save > iptsave.sh` (the .sh is to enable the nice vim highlighting)
2. `vi iptsave.sh` and do your changes
3. `iptables-apply -t 600 iptsave.sh` = 600 seconds of testing time, after which `iptables-apply` automatically reverts to the prior ruleset. Or, you can press <kbd>y</kbd> and the new ruleset becomes permanent. **DO NOT USE `<` THERE!!** `iptables-apply` accepts a file name as an *argument*, not as a STDIN.
4. `mv iptsave.sh /etc/iptables.rules`

---

> And within the main iptables conf file another iptables rules file can be linked which can be made editable by users who have less privileges.

But why??

The iptables ruleset is meant to be made once, and modified only every now and then. If you have to keep changing it all the time, I think you're not implementing iptables in the most efficient/effective way.

---

#### Customizable & Updatable MAC rules

First of all, ensure that MAC testing branches off to a different chain. I suggest also 'splitting' the INPUT chain (I drop the `iptables` command for brevity)

```
-N MAC_admins
-N MAC_users
-N INPUT_2
-A INPUT -j MAC_admins
-A INPUT -j MAC_users
-A INPUT -j DROP
... rest of -A INPUT is put into -A INPUT_2 ...
```

`MAC_admins` is for the admins' MAC addresses, so it won't get hosed (and thus locking you out):

```
-A MAC_admins -m mac --mac-source 11:11:11:11:11:11 -g INPUT_2
-A MAC_admins -m mac --mac-source 22:22:22:22:22:22 -g INPUT_2
-A MAC_admins -m mac --mac-source 33:33:33:33:33:33 -g INPUT_2
```

Users whose MAC does not match anything there will be returned to the INPUT chain, and endure the 2nd MAC-checking chain. Now, to populate this chain, let's make a script. Assume it's `/etc/firewall/UpdateMAC.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
readonly CONFDIR="/etc/firewall/maclists"
readonly IPT="/sbin/iptables"
readonly WORKCHAIN="MAC_users"
readonly NEXTCHAIN="INPUT_2"

readonly MACPATTERN="^([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}$"

# Flush the chain (i.e., remove all rules in the chain)
$IPT -F $WORKCHAIN

for f in $CONFDIR/*
do
  while read mac; do
    [[ -z $mac ]] && continue           # Skip empty lines
    [[ ${mac:0:1} == "#" ]] && continue # Skip comments (if any)
    # A regex check to ensure that $mac indeed contains a MAC address
    if [[ $mac =~ $MACPATTERN ]]; then
      $IPT -A $WORKCHAIN -m mac --mac-source $mac -g $NEXTCHAIN
    fi
  done < $f
done

exit 0
# Tested on bash v4
```

Now do some magic with `chmod` and `chown`. Have your subadmins edit one (or more) files under `/etc/firewall/maclists/`, and whenever they've edited their file(s), you just execute the script.

Comment: I use MAC ids in the iptables to restrict users. I have rules for my 500 users. So I want to use two scripts: One for securtiy and forwarding and another for user MAC ids. The first one should be accessible only for me (as it provides security) and the second one should be editable for my collegues who are helping me to add and remove users. And the most important thing I want is to be able to do `service firewall restart` which should load rules from both the scripts.

Comment: @nixnotwin ah, I see. The solution will depend on whether you want an 'absolute' filter against MAC (i.e., only certain MACs are allowed, the others are totally blocked), or not. For an absolute MAC filter, you can use `arptables`. For a non-absolute MAC filter, you should use `ipset`, especially the `ipmacmap` (for pre-5 version) or `bitmap:ip,mac` (version 5+) type. In both cases, you can make just a single iptables ruleset that does not change; only the contents of the arptables/ipset change.

Comment: I have the macs which I want to allow in the script, and all others are blocked. I use this: `iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source 00:8c:c3:de:67:8a -j RETURN` and
`iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP` With the first line repeated for each user. The `arptables` sounds better than mine. Are there any good howtos?

Comment: @nixnotwin well, the arptables is just like iptables, but much simpler. just read its man page. it has only 2 'chains', `IN` and `OUT`. you just add allowed MAC addresses in the IN chain, and then change the chain's policy to `DROP`. afterwards, just manipulate it using `arptables -A IN` and `arptables -D IN`. it also has `arptables-save` and `arptables-restore`. there *is* a slight drawback: as the name implies, it basically works on `ARP`. cunning users using static ARP entries may bypass its protection.

Comment: @nixnotwin in the case of the cunning user, you'll have to either go the `ipset` way, or 'branch off' the set of MAC testing. then write a script that runs in the background and checks for changes to a file containing a list of MACs, and do a Flush-then-Repopulate against that single chain, e.g., `-F MAClist` followed by a scripted series of `-A MAClist`s.

Comment: @nixtnotwin I've edited my answer with the 'pure iptables' solution.

Comment: Extremely thankful for taking time to give me a soultion to my issue. But somehow I feel Sacx's answer a bit adaptable.  Here is the customized vesrion of `iptables-persistent` script: http://pastebin.com/Xb08S6s4 Please do provide your suggestions. the file `macaccess.sh` will have rules for each user in the syntax I refered to in my eariler comment. Massive thanks.

Comment: @nixnotwin that will work. one suggestion from me would be to also use `iptables-restore` instead of a series of `iptables` in the portion of script preceding the `. macaccess.sh` part. this is because each invocation of iptables is much more expensive than iptables-restore due to how iptables work: extract the ruleset from kernel, modify, push the ruleset back into kernel. iptables-restore just do a single bulk-push of ruleset into kernel.

Comment: @nixnotwin an additional thought: I think source-ing macaccess.sh is *dangerous*. you're practically executing unsanitized code there. in addition, a mistake in macaccess.sh will make the whole initscript grinds to a halt. rather than source-ing, loop through a .conf file like I did in my answer. modify the script according to your needs. since the loop I wrote above is bash-specific, put it in a separate script and call -- not source -- it from the init script, thus properly invoking bash.

Comment: One more thing: https and www rules should use `-p tcp` instead of `-p udp`. and the generic multiport rules should also have their `-p tcp` counterparts. there are other possible 'gotchas' I see in your script. I'll edit my answer when I reach office to address those 'gotchas'.

Comment: @pepoluan As per your advice I will use `iptables-resstore` for whatever line that begin with `iptables` in my pastebin script: #
`if [ -f /etc/iptables/myrules ]; then` 
 `iptables-restore </etc/iptables/myrulesrules`... And next to it I will have your bash script:`if [ -f /etc/iptables/pepoluan_script ]; then` 
 `iptables-restore </etc/iptables/pepoluan_script`

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar question, but its on this topic, so i figure I'll share my two cents and ask...

First off, on a server it is highly feasible to have an iptables ruleset that changes frequently. I don't know who would think not. If you run port scan detection software, or other types of IPS (intrusion prevention software), these programs can be configured to add deny rules for specific attacking hosts to your iptables configuration. If that is the case, you will likely want these deny rules committed to the save files when iptables stops, or restarts.

That being said, don't deplore him for wanting a way to dynamically update iptables. I'm fishing around for the same thing.

To answer this question, there is a package called iptables-persistent that can be installed via "apt-get iptables-persistent". It will commit the iptables rules loaded at the time and create files for them, then create a boot script to reload those rules at boot, or firewall restart.

I know that some sources say there is a config file for iptables-persistent that allows it to commit changes to the firewall rules, but I'm running Ubuntu Server v13, and I can't seen to find that file anywhere. I guess whoever can post a path to it answers both our questions. :p